# Can I use Hyper-V disk snapshot/checkpoint ability on Windows 10's virtual disk?

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, vhdx

I develop applications and sometime I zip the folder to make a checkpoint and if the things go wrong I delete the folder and unzip the files back. And its time consuming process.

Can't I use virtual disk and snapshot function, so Windows creates new file for virtual disk and writes into it any changes, etc?

P.S: I'm not using virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V Checkpoints work in Windows 10.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints

Comment: I'm not using virtual machine.